# A Question about Continuous functions. How to Prove that: $\inf_{\forall f(x) \in C[a,b]}\{ \sup_{f(x)} K \}= \frac{b-a}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

$C[a,b]$ is the set of all continuous functions on $[a,b]$.

$f(x)$ is continuous function on $[a,b]\,$ ($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$) , such that $f(a)=f(b)$, $\forall \varepsilon \in (0,K),\, \exists x_{0}$, s.t. $f(x_{0})=f(x_{0}+\varepsilon)$.

For all $K$ satisfies the above conditions, $\inf_{\forall f(x) \in C[a,b]}\{ \sup_{f(x)} K \}$ is equal $\frac{b-a}{2}$ ?

How to prove: $\inf_{\forall f(x) \in C[a,b]}\{ \sup_{f(x)} K \}= \frac{b-a}{2}$

---

For example, $x$ on [0,1]:

if $f(x)=\sin(\pi*x)$, Obviously, $\sup_{f(x)} K=1$;

[$f(x)=\sin(\pi*x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX2wj.gif)

if $f(x)=\sin(2\pi*x)$, Obviously, $\sup_{f(x)} K=1/2$;

[$f(x)=\sin(2\pi*x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4y3w.gif)

So how to prove $\inf_{\forall f(x) \in C[a,b]}\{ \sup_{f(x)} K \} =\frac{b-a}{2}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type `\sin` in order to get $\sin$.

Comment: Hi..., I cannot understand the term $\inf \{ \sup K \}$ . As the set of $K$ s satisfying this relation is a bounded set so it has an $\inf$ and a $\sup$. Or do you mean that if we run through the set of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ we have the following equality?

Comment: Yep, the set of continuous functions on [,]

Comment: "C(x) is the set of all continuous functions on [a,b]." That notation could be confusing. $C[a,b]$ or just $C$ is better.

Comment: Nice question! Where did you get this from?

Comment: This is a question I raised unintentionally. I am a student in applied, and I was reviewing real-analysis recently. On Wednesday, I saw a similar problem: $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, and $f(0)=f(1),\, \forall n \ge 2  (n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}),\, \exists x_{0},\, $s.t.$ \; f(x_{0})=f(x_{0}+\frac{1}{n})$. It can be proved by the cumulative method.  Then I think it is not necessarily to equal $\frac{1}{n}$, irrational numbers can also be used.  So I raised this question, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer doesn't work.
Let's call $B \subset C[a,b]$ the subset of the continuous functions such that there exists such a $K > 0$, because there are functions $f \in C[a,b]$ for which the only $K\in \mathbb R$ that fits is $K=0$, for example $f(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$. Then the infimum has to run over $B$. 
That being said, I don't think that that $\inf_{f \in B} \big( \sup_{K_f>0} K_f \big) = \frac{b-a} 2$ is true. Let $\delta >0$ and consider the function $$f (x) := \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for } x \in [0, \delta ) \\ \frac {x - \delta }{1-\delta } & \text{for } x \in [\delta ,1] \end{cases}$$
(This function is constant from $0$ to $\delta $ and then linearly increases from $\delta $ to $1$).
We have $f \in B$ because it is continuous and for any $K< \delta$ it fits the condition  from your question (But no $K>\delta$ fits!). Because $\delta > 0$ is arbitrary we get that $$\inf_{f \in B} \left( \sup_{K_f>0} K_f \right) = 0$$

Comment: The $f$ you have chosen doesn't satisfy $f(0) = f(1)$, hence there is a problem.

Comment: ah I see. you're right

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway.